# How to handle view with keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uikeyboard

I am having 2+ years of experience in iOS development. I haven't got the better solution for the keyboard handling. I need to handle it by the notifications and that old stuff. Is there any library or any simple stuff that could automatically handle the keyboard and view.

Because handling these things manually takes too much time. So please let me know if you guys are having something new approach to handle this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @BhavinRamani Thank you. But have you any other approach which can be done by our self without the open source code.

Comment: If you don't want to use other library then you should use notification's keyboard event.

Comment: IQKeyboardManager is using a singleton observer for the keyboard event and get top most view controller and stuff to push up, you can do the same also if you want recreate it

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. The user taps in the text field, the keyboard appears automatically. What do you need to "handle"?

Comment: [this will help you](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is library named `TPKeyboardAvoiding` you can download files [here](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding/tree/master/TPKeyboardAvoiding).
As you said "handling these things manually takes too much time", so it will be better just give class to scrollview to `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` & it will handle all cases.

Comment: No, as these classes currently adjust the contentInset parameter to avoid content moving beneath the keyboard. This is done, as opposed to adjusting the frame, in order to work around an iOS bug that results in a jerky animation where the view jumps upwards, before settling down.